# Add days to current date from MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date, addition, days

I have a fixed date from MySql

```
startDate = 07/03/2011
```

I wanted to add 60 days on top this date to have an endDate.

```
$startDate = $result['startDate'];
$endDate = ??? + strtotime("+60 days");
echo $endDate;
```

From my research, I know it has something do with strtotime, but all the sites I come across with based the start date from current workstation's time. My date is already fixed and entered prior to running and getting the endDate.

Help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to PHP solutions others are providing, you can create the `endDate` right inside of MySQL and save yourself some of the trouble:

```
SELECT startDate, DATE_ADD(startDate, INTERVAL 60 DAY) AS endDate FROM table;

-- Or by months (not exactly the same thing)
SELECT startDate, DATE_ADD(startDate, INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AS endDate FROM table;
```

[Relevant documentation here...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

Comment: In fact you don't need the DATE_ADD(), it's just about the INTERVAL. Try: `SELECT startDate, startDate + INTERVAL 2 MONTH AS endDate FROM table;`

Answer (score 5):

You could reformat the results of `strtotime()`

```
$startDate = $result['startDate']; // 07/03/2011
$endDate = date("m/d/Y", strtotime("$startDate +60 days"));
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/9rWnoeQb

Answer (score 2):

```
$startDate = "07/03/2011";
$endDate = strtotime("+60 days",time($startDate));
$formatted = date('m/d/Y',$endDate);
echo $endDate . "<br/>" . $formatted;
```

Answer (score 1):

86400 seconds in a day, times number of days.. and add it to current time.

```
$nextMonth = time()+86400*60;
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $nextMonth);
```